# Detect what object was clicked via event trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events

I've been messing around with unity's event triggers and I am wondering if there is a way to get the name of an object that has been clicked by an event trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I've done some googling and found out that the code I was using needed to add a `GameObject gameObject` parameter.